# Jenkins Mercurial plugin gives error: partial pull cannot be done because other repository doesn't support changegroupsubset

Tags: version-control, mercurial, jenkins, build-automation

I'm having an issue with setting up jenkins for build automation, we use the source control host codebasehq, with mercurial, however it is failing to pull from the repo.

The plugin seems to connect fine with the supplied credentials (at the moment we're simply using the in http url credentials) but then gives the following error:

```
Building in workspace /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace 
$ hg clone --rev tip --noupdate https://foo:bar@initech.codebasehq.com/foo/bar.hg /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace
abort: partial pull cannot be done because other repository doesn't support changegroupsubset.
```

I've tried running the command in the error message, but it simply returns the same abort message.

I have limited experience with mercurial, and google doesn't seem to return much on the error message, which makes me think it might either be an issue with the jenkins plugin, or codebasehq's mercurial setup.

Any information on the error or if anyone has experience with setting up this kind of thing on codebasehq successfully and could share any advice would be fantastic.

Comment: I suspect it's related to the version of mercurial you're using in codebasehq, versus the version your repository is.  Codebasehq is probably newer.

Comment: @sonofagun The server has just been set up particularly for this purpose, so I'd very recently run a sudo apt-get install mercurial, this seems to have installed version 2.0.2, though the latest version available for my platform seems to be 2.3.2. I've updated using their ppa, but alas, the issue persists. I don't suppose you'd know a way of checking the codebasehq mercurial version?

Comment: Since you appear to have access to the command line, try 'hg version'.  [edit:] Sorry, you'd have to do that on their server.  I don't have codebasehq; you could contact their support.  If that's too difficult, you could download the latest [link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) `mercurial` and upgrade your repository.  Just back it up first! :)

Comment: @sonofagun Sadly, I don't have ssh access to the codebasehq server, so I've submitted a support request with them for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a response from the codebasehq support team, it seems that 'changegroupsubset' refers to a feature that is unsupported by the https version of their mercurial repository. It is however, supported by the ssh version of their repository, so I was able to fix this by simply replacing

```
hg clone --rev tip --noupdate https://foo:bar@initech.codebasehq.com/foo/bar.hg /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace
```

with

```
hg clone --rev tip --noupdate ssh://foo:bar@initech.codebasehq.com/foo/bar.hg /home/ubuntu/jenkins/jobs/testJob/workspace
```

And this worked successfully.